# Webview20.9.430 library is failed to create environment

Tags: webview2

The older version of my application is using webview2 (0.9.430).
We received a complaint from a customer that the edge browser is not loading on the application, which was working earlier.

CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails() method is failing to create environment with ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error.

The customer has canary version Version 94.0.974.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit).
webview2  libraries of version 0.9.430.

Does anyone know if something has changed in webview2/Edge browser regarding legacy compatibility?

Is there any way to address the issue other than updating the webview2 libraries? Because updating webview2 requires the API changes, which will be considered a major release, not a patch release.
So I need to avoid major releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions before 1.0.0.0 are preview releases of the SDK for which compatibility will be dropped at some point. Specifically for 0.9.430.0, you can see the [0.9.430.0 nuget package was deprecated and delisted](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/0.9.430) and [the 430 deprecation was called out in the release notes in Feb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes#10790-prerelease).

Unfortunately the only way forward is to move to a post 1.0.0.0 nuget package version.

With versions 1.0.0.0 and forward compatibility is maintained for all APIs that show up in release nuget packages. So you shouldn't run into this sort of problem again after moving to a post 1.0.0.0 nuget package. This [webview2 versioning document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/versioning#forward-compatibility-of-apis) covers compatibility in more detail.